# How to use React Native basic hooks example?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I recently started app development with React Native. Therefore I am trying to implement a button that switches between two boolean states with values via hooks. Right now the button works once, but I can't toggle the value back. I am trying to create a custom button, so the switch from React is not an option. Do you have any fixes or tips for me?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, View,Text } from 'react-native';

export const Notes =({}) => { 
 //   
    const [score, setScore] = useState(1);

    const handlepress = () => {
        score ? setScore(1): setScore(2);
    }
    return (    
        <View>  
        <Text>{score}</Text>
            <Button title= "Take Number" onPress= {handlepress}>
            </Button>    
            <Text> Test{score}</Text>
        </View>    
);}
```

Comment: `score ? setScore(1): setScore(2);` will call `setScore(1)` if `score` is any *truthy* value. Both `1` and `2` are truthy, so that code will always call `setScore(1)`. If you want to go back and forth between `1` and `2`, you need to change the condition you're testing. (Also, I recommend `if` statements, not freestanding conditional expressions.)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply T.J. Will definitely look into this & use if statements in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
export const Notes =({}) => { 

    const [score, setScore] = useState(1); // add score here 

    const handlepress = () => {
        score === 2 ? setScore(1): setScore(2);
    }
    return (    
        <View>  
        <Text>{`${score}`}</Text>
            ...    
            <Text>{`Test${score}`}</Text>
        </View>    
);}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I'm getting the error ReferenceError: score is not defined. Is there any syntax error?

Comment: @Chris update my answer please check

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked perfectly. I will dig into it to understand, what you did differently! @nooruddin

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `0` and `1` for the `score` variable. `1` and `2` are both truthy values and the state will never change.